# How to deploy Babylon.js app to Hololens Emulator

Tags: hololens, babylonjs, hololens-emulator

I have developed a simple application with babylon.js in a file called index.html, but I don't know how to run it on Hololens Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can host the file as a Azure Static Web App and access it from a browser (Edge 81 on Windows Desktop, Edge 91 on Hololens 2) or follow these docs to learn how you can host it locally or on other device within same network [Tutorial: Create your first WebXR application using Babylon.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/javascript/tutorials/babylonjs-webxr-helloworld/introduction-01)
You can use the emulator in both scenarios for tests.